# View all unplayed podcasts in Zune desktop software

Tags: podcasts, zune, zune-software

When using the Zune desktop software, is it possible to view a list of all unplayed downloaded podcasts?

I don't want to have to keep looking through each individual subscribed podcast for any new shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have just discovered that in the QUICKPLAY view, the NEW group includes newly downloaded and unplayed podcasts as well as other new content. If there aren't to many they should all be viewable there.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a feature for that in the current version of Zune. I've looked a couple of times, but haven't found a sollution.

Comment: That's what I suspected, but I thought I'd ask around to check. :(